# No option to see Work Items in Team Explorer, VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, team-explorer

I have 2 projects in Visual Studio Online, one created recently. After creating the new project the Work Items options disappeared from Team Explorer in the older project but was available in the new project.

I couldn't find out how to get the Work Items to display in the older proejct and so re-cloned it which brought the display of work items back. However this seemed to cause the display of Work Items to disappear from the new project. Here is how the respective projects currently look...

Team Explorer Options in new project...
[image: Team Explorer options in older project]

Team Explorer Options in older project...
[image: Team Explorer Options in new project]

How do I get Team Explorer to display Work Items for both projects?